# Glitchy lighting for volumetric clouds

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I'm new to Blender and followed a tutorial I found online https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPAYX8z9i8M&t=495s to create a procedural cloud.

I got a single cloud right, however, when I scaled it up things started becoming glitchy.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Use a point light instead of a sun lamp. Sun lamps create shadows in one direction regardless of their placement, whereas a point light (or a spot or area light) emits only from a specific coordinate in the 3D environment.

Comment: Changing the light source to a point light instead of a sun makes the clouds seem very flat though. The striped shadows are gone, though the render image looks very flat as there are no shadows. Is there a way to emulate the sun using the point light?

Comment: The light has to be behind the clouds, then just increase the brightness on the world's color so that the foregrounds elements can be seen. In the real world you would have the sun behind the clouds, and the volumetrics would be suspended particles on the air. The rest of the illumination would come from the light reflected on the atmosphere.